# What is the significance of the number 117 for hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, web

It is gone now, but for a long time the "advanced problems" page at the hibernate website was:

http://www.hibernate.org/117.html

Why was it 117.html? Was there some sort of significance to this particular number?

Comment: 42 was already taken. So they took (42 * 3) - 9 = 117 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No significance, this is just how their CMS used to work. It created pages with not so helpful names (and maybe not even permlinkable, not sure about that).

As you have pointed out, the URL goes somewhere else now, so they have "fixed" it.

Comment: Many CMSs do this.  Drupal, for one.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: Are those pages still linkable? Or do they all get renumbered when you add a new one "in the middle"?

Comment: Drupal allows you to set a "nice" alias for the node number (that's what they call the page), so you can access it either way.  Maybe hibernate did it that way, maybe they didn't, I haven't looked at the site to see what CMS they used.